# How to create SQlite database in UTF-16 format only?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to the SQLite, I want to create the Database in UTF-16 format only as per the requirement but

```
  database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_FILE_PATH
                + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

always giving me the Database which is UTF-8 only. So can anybody tell me how to do it. I will definitely appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Android database API does not allow this.
(It's not needed anyway; all strings are Unicode, regardless of Java's or SQLite's internal encoding.)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to call

`db.execSQL("PRAGMA encoding = UTF-16;");`

Check [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding).